# Informix window function range clause behaves like rows clause

Tags: sql, informix, window-functions

Consider this statement in **Informix**:

```sql
SELECT 
  a, 
  b,
  sum(a) over (order by b) "no frame",
  sum(a) over (order by b range between unbounded preceding and current row) "range",
  sum(a) over (order by b rows between unbounded preceding and current row) "rows"
FROM TABLE(SET{row(1, 1), row(2, 1), row(3, 2), row(4, 2)}) AS t(a, b);
```

Surprisingly, it produces the same result for `range` and `rows`:

```
a |b |no frame |range |rows |
--|--|---------|------|-----|
1 |1 |3        |1     |1    |
2 |1 |3        |3     |3    |
3 |2 |10       |6     |6    |
4 |2 |10       |10    |10   |
```

This works quite differently from any RDBMS I'm used to, including **PostgreSQL**:

```sql
SELECT 
  a, 
  b,
  sum(a) over (order by b) "no frame",
  sum(a) over (order by b range between unbounded preceding and current row) "range",
  sum(a) over (order by b rows between unbounded preceding and current row) "rows"
FROM (values(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 2)) AS t(a, b);
```

... which produces the expected

```
a |b |no frame |range |rows |
--|--|---------|------|-----|
1 |1 |3        |3     |1    |
2 |1 |3        |3     |3    |
3 |2 |10       |10    |6    |
4 |2 |10       |10    |10   |
```

Is there a subtle difference between Informix and standard SQL that I'm missing, or is it a bug? I'm using the [official docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/informix-developer-database/), which corresponds to Informix 12.10 as of now.

Comment: This behavior seems to be corrected in Informix version 12.10.XC13 . But it is still incorrect in Informix 14.10XC1 .

Answer (score 1):

This is [documented](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_2584.htm) behavior:

> If you specify an ORDER clause but no window frame clause for a window aggregation function, then by default, all rows that precede the current row and the current row are returned, which is equivalent to the following window frame specification:
>
> ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW

I believe the standard is `RANGE` when no windowing clause is present.  I'm pretty sure that is the default in most other databases.

Comment: That's interesting, because that's not at all what happens :) The frame-less version is correct according to the standard (but not to this description), and the version using `RANGE` is wrong!

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I can use `0 PRECEDING` (which shouldn't be allowed, but oh well) instead of `CURRENT ROW`. This produces the result I would have expected:

```sql
SELECT 
  a, 
  b,
  sum(a) over (order by b) "no frame",
  sum(a) over (order by b range between unbounded preceding and 0 preceding) "range",
  sum(a) over (order by b rows between unbounded preceding and current row) "rows"
FROM (values(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 2)) AS t(a, b);
```

I now get:

```
a |b |no frame |range |rows |
--|--|---------|------|-----|
1 |1 |3        |3     |1    |
2 |1 |3        |3     |3    |
3 |2 |10       |10    |6    |
4 |2 |10       |10    |10   |
```